# How to overwrite default collection on deserialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a class which represents a bunch of settings:

```
public class Settings
{
   public Settings()
   {
       InnerSettings = new List<InnerSettings>();
       //this is the settings i want to have by default
       InnerSettings.Add(new InnerSettings());
   }
   [XmlArray]
   public List<InnerSettings> InnerSettings {get; set;}
}
```

Now, when I deserialize this object, the `InnerSettings` from XML are added to the `List` on top of the items which were created in default `Settings()` constructor. Is there an easy way to tell deserializer, that I want to overwrite the collection instead, removing the default items?

Comment: You want to deserialize everything except `InnerSettings`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I want to deserialize everything, but I don't want the `InnerSettings`, added in default `Settings()` constructor, to be present in deserialized object (unless they present in XML as well).

Comment: Create a base class with default settings.  The have your Settings class inherit the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML Serializer doesn't support any callback and deriving from `XmlSerializer` class there are few methods you can override. Let's see some (dirty) workarounds:

1) Change default constructor (the one `XmlSerializer` will call) to do not include default item(s). Add a second constructor with a dummy parameter and expose a factory method:

```
public class Settings {
   private Settings() {
       // Called by XmlDeserializer
   }

   private Settings(int dummy) {
       // Called by factory method
       InnerSettings = new List<InnerSettings> { new InnderSettings(); }
   }

   public static Settings Create() {
       return new Settings(0);
   }
}
```

2) Remove items after object has been deserialized. Create your own `XmlSerializer` for this:

```
public class SettingsXmlSerializer : XmlSerializer {
    protected override object Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader) {
        var settings = (Settings)base.Deserialize(reader);
        settings.InnerSettings.RemoveAt(0);

        return settings;
    }
}
```

3) It should be right way to do it but it's not easy for complex types: the long job of `IXmlSerializable` implementation...

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a static property on Settings class to hold the default preset and removing this logic from default constructor. I wonder why serialization works this way though. Why does it add items to existing collection, insted of recreating it? What's the use case for such behaviour?

Comment: Because XML serialization simply invokes default constructor to create a new object. Then populates that instance with data from XML file. It makes initialization code _easier_ but counter intuitive if you're used to other serialization mechanisms.

Comment: well, yes, callng the default constructor before deserialization makes sense. What does not quite make sense is that instead of calling set accessor on `List<T>` properties, overwriting the collection, deserializer actually calls `IList.Add` method. This does not strike me as an easier thing to do, nor does it seem consistent with the way deserializer treats properties of other types.

Comment: Yes, it's not! But it has advantage to _emulate_ how your object is used in code then all your mechanisms still works as expected (for example if you attach an event handler to every added items).